# Why is invalid data saved to database anyway when custom `create` method is used?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm creating a custom `create` method to process incoming data. It gets validated by a serializer:

```py
# serializers.py:
class ItemVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   item_ver_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^r\d{2}$', allow_blank=False)
   session_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^s\d{2}$', allow_blank=False)
   config = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)
   item_ver = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)

(...)
```

The method itself looks like this:

```py
# views.py:
class ItemVersionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = ItemVersionSerializer
   lookup_field = 'item_ver_id'

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       data = request.data

       model = ItemModel.objects.get(item_id=data["model"])
       finished = True if "finished" in data else False

       item_version = ItemVersion.objects.create(
          model=model,
          item_ver_id=data["item_ver_id"],
          config=data["config"],
          item_ver=data["item_ver"],
          session_id=data["session_id"],
          finished=finished
       )

       serializer = ItemVersionSerializer(data=request.data)

       if serializer.is_valid():
          # item_version.save() # data gets saved even with this line off
          return Response(serializer.validated_data)
        else:
           return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When passing incorrect data, e.g. too short `item_ver` string, I receive error 400 and this info:

```js
{
    "item_ver": [
        "Ensure this field has at least 6 characters."
    ]
}
```

However, when I correct the data and send it again, I receive `IntegrityError`: `UNIQUE constraint failed: core_itemversion.item_ver_id` and looking at the list of instances I can see the new entry saved to the database anyway.

Which method is responsible for saving the data?

Comment: you are creating object in view not serializer. How serializer will handle this data?

Comment: Custom create method is written in serializer not in you view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you validate your serializer BEFORE creating. Like this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

As you can see, there is no need for if else when doing serializer.is_valid(), just use raise_exception=True, and the viewset will make sure that the response will be a 400_BAD_REQUEST.

Second, don't do `Model.objects.create()`, then save. Do ModelSerializer(request.data), and then follow the convention.

Hopefully this makes sense to you, do let me know if you need me to expand.